# Java Swing custom JList cellRenderer not painting all elements after adding new one

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint, jlist

So this is my first bigger project as a newbie. This project is mainly a Swing GUI application, which is basically an apartment hunter app. Actually, this is a very big program(for me at least), and the code is very messy, but i will try my best to include everything that is essential.
So in the program, one of the JPanel contains a Jlist, which contains all the available apartments, and has a custom cellRenderer class. Which looks like this(i will detail everything after the code snippet):

```
class PanelRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {


        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

                    Pair pair = sqldata.getInfo((String)value);
                    if(MainController.data_storage!=null){
                        ImageIcon final_img = MainController.data_storage.get((String)value).get(0); //(String)value is From nameList array
                        label.setIcon(final_img); 
                        
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> tmp = sqldata.apartmentDetails(pair.getValue()+"");
                    
                    if(tmp.size()>0){
                        ids.add(tmp.get(tmp.size()-1));
                    }
                                 
                    label.setText("<html>Title: "+pair.getValue()+" <br/> Price: "+pair.getKey()+"  <br/> Owner: "+value+"<br/>  <br/>"
                            + " Room type: "+tmp.get(0)+"       <br/>        Room num: "+tmp.get(1)+"     <br/>         "
                                    + " Balcony:           "+(tmp.get(2).equals("true") ? "<font color='green'>✓</font>" : "<font color='red'>×</font>")+"        "
                                    + "       Pet: "+(tmp.get(3).equals("true") ? "<font color='green'>✓</font>" : "<font color='red'>×</font>")+" "
                                    + "               Yard: "+(tmp.get(4).equals("true") ? "<font color='green'>✓</font>" : "<font color='red'>×</font>")+"           "
                                            + "    Smoke: "+(tmp.get(5).equals("true") ? "<font color='green'>✓</font>" : "<font color='red'>×</font>")+"     "
                                            + "     Quiet: "+(tmp.get(6).equals("true") ? "<font color='green'>✓</font>" : "<font color='red'>×</font>")+" "
                                            + "               Deposit: "+(tmp.get(7).equals("true") ? "<font color='green'>✓</font>" : "<font color='red'>×</font>")+"</html>");
                    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
                    value = tmp.get(tmp.size()-1);
            return label;
        }
    }
```

So this line: `Pair pair = sqldata.getInfo((String)value);` Returns the price, and the title for an apartment.

This line: `ImageIcon final_img = MainController.data_storage.get((String)value).get(0);` Returns the image(s) associated with the owners name for an apartment.

The next line: `ArrayList<String> tmp = sqldata.apartmentDetails(pair.getValue()+"");` Returns the rest of the stuff for an apartment. eg.: City, room type, pet, etc. So one list item has an image, and some text in it.

My app has a search button, which gets all the data from the sql server when pressed, and downloads the corresponding data from a remote FTP server. And after that, the Jlist displays the result. There are filter options too, like Balcony, Pet, Price and city. These are working fine so far. The problem occurs after i upload a new apartment. If i click the search button after uploading the new apartment, everything gets returned back correctly(internally, like lists), except all the painted elems on the list. Because nothing is painted. So after the insert(upload), the data was inserted into SQL Table, Image uploaded onto FTP server. This part is fine. Furthermore, when i refresh the arrayList which gives the elements to the JList, it tells me the new apartment is in it(and the old ones too). But nothing is shown on the JList, it is completely blank. This code is doing the upload:

```
if(validFile()){
                 if(!uploadMenuValidate()){
                   if(!img_container.isEmpty()){ 
                    for(File f : img_container){
                     try {
                         ftp.putFileToPath(f, FtpClient.DEST_DIR+SQLData.APP_USERNAME+"/"+f.getName());

                     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                         ex.printStackTrace();
                         } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }
                           sqldata.insert(SQLData.QUERY_ADD_APARTMENT, SQLData.APP_USERNAME,uploadmenu.getPriceField().getText(),uploadmenu.getCityField().getText(),uploadmenu.getRoomTypeSelector().getSelectedItem().toString(),
                                   uploadmenu.getRoomNum().getText(),uploadmenu.getBalconyCheck().isSelected()+"",uploadmenu.getPetCheck().isSelected()+"",uploadmenu.getYardCheck().isSelected()+"",uploadmenu.getSmokeCheck().isSelected()+"",
                                   uploadmenu.getFreqCheck().isSelected()+"",uploadmenu.getDepositCheck().isSelected()+"",img_container.size()>0 ? FtpClient.DEST_DIR+SQLData.APP_USERNAME+"/"+img_container.get(0).getName() : "",
                                   img_container.size()>1 ? FtpClient.DEST_DIR+SQLData.APP_USERNAME+"/"+img_container.get(1).getName() : "",img_container.size()>2 ? FtpClient.DEST_DIR+SQLData.APP_USERNAME+"/"+img_container.get(2).getName() : "",
                                   img_container.size()>3 ? FtpClient.DEST_DIR+SQLData.APP_USERNAME+"/"+img_container.get(3).getName() : "",uploadmenu.getDetailsBox().getText(),uploadmenu.getApTitle().getText(),mainc.getUniqueId());
                           
                           showInfoPanel("misc.INFO_UPLOAD_SUCCESS");

    
                                   data_storage = mainc.getApartments(sqldata.getApartments()); 
         }
    }
}
```

Here: `data_storage = mainc.getApartments(sqldata.getApartments());` The internal ArrayList gets refreshed, which is basically contains the elements of the JList.

Some more code that could be important:

```
mainJListPanel = new JList(nameList);

public String[] nameList = makeList();

     public String[] makeList(){
        
        int n = sqldata.getApartments().size();
        HashMap<String,List<String>> kt = sqldata.getApartments();
        String[] tmp =new String[n];
        ids = new ArrayList<>();
        
        
         int i = 0;
        for (String x : kt.keySet()){
            tmp[i++] = x; //Getting the owner names
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    
    public static String[] searchList(){
        int n = MainController.data_storage.size();
        String[] tmp = new String[n];
        
        int i = 0;
        for (String x : MainController.data_storage.keySet()){
            tmp[i++] = x;
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

And the search button does this:

```
data_storage = getApartments(sqldata.getSearchedApartments(mainmenu.getMenuMinPrice().getText()+"",mainmenu.getMenuMaxPrice().getText(),mainmenu.getMenuCity().getText(),
                String.valueOf((int)mainmenu.getMenuRoomNum().getValue()),mainmenu.getMenuRoomType().getSelectedItem()+"",mainmenu.getMenuBalcony().isSelected()+"",mainmenu.getMenuYard().isSelected()+"",mainmenu.getMenuPet().isSelected()+"",
                mainmenu.getMenuSmoke().isSelected()+"",mainmenu.getMenuFreq().isSelected()+"",mainmenu.getMenuDeposit().isSelected()+"", mainmenu.getMenuMiscText().getText()));
 //Getting everything from the filter, and //converting it into an SQL query --> This is working, the sql command is OK. 
            
            mainmenu.setNameList(mainmenu.searchList());
            mainmenu.getMenuMainPanel().revalidate();
            mainmenu.getMenuMainPanel().repaint();
//mainmenu is the instance of the JPanel, which contains the Jlist
```

The strange thing is, if i check a filter option, like Balcony, the JList paints the result. Even the new apartment is in the result, which was uploaded. But when i remove all the filters, (So basically i want every apartment back), the list wont paint anything. So the error comes only if i'm a in a state of "after uploading", and i want every apartment to be painted on the Jlist. If i restart the program, the new apartment will be painted on the list, and everything works fine until i upload a new apartment again.

Comment: This isn't something we're going to be able to solve - as we don't have the full picture or a way to easily replicate it - instead, you're going to need to go back to some basic debugging.  I'd start with identifying if the `ListModel` actually contains any data after the update (ie `ListModel#getSize`) - if it doesn't - I'd check what the results of your query are, if it does, I'd move on to the renderer and see what it's doing.  Beware not to download images within the context if the event dispatching thread, this will cause you app to "hang" while the operation completes.

Comment: This is where a local cache and observer pattern would be most useful.  Remember to make your renderer as dumb as possible, it shouldn't be doing things which might change the state of the list only represent the current state of the data it's been given

Comment: Ah, unfortunately you are right, in order to solve this, i would have to share everything, but thats impossible here. :( Howewer, I started debugging, and the ListModel gives back the correct size, which sholud be there. And i printed every data, and everything is there. So the ListModel, and all the related arrays are successfully updated, and they are containing fresh data. So i think that is fine. Howewer, nothing gets painted. On the JList. I will move on to the renderer. And ah yes, i did put the downloading part into a second thread meanwhile.

Comment: If you can determine that the `JList` is using the correct model, verify that it's attempting to render the data, if that's getting called, consider reducing the complexity of the renderer

Comment: Well, i saved the initial listModel, which was initialized by the constructor. And after uploading and pressing search, i did an `initial-listmodel.equals(listmodel-after-uploading)` check, and it returns true. Idk if that is a proper way to check listModel equality. Furthermore, there is no such code in the program that would attempt to edit the internal listmodel. Btw, how can i verify that the list is attempting to render the data?

Comment: Put a println statement at the start of the renderer

Comment: It is not rendering. The println gets called many times at the program startup, and at other  operations too. But after uploading and search, it wont execute. Idk why. And i read that u cant call that custom renderer explicitly. So i cant force it either.

Comment: If the model is getting updated but the render isn't been called, I suggest that there is a issue between the model and jlist somewhere, either you're updating the wrong model, not assigning it to the jlist or not updating the jlist on the screen